# Can I get less(1) to display the final line, without selecting it?

Tags: terminal, command-line

When less(1) is looking at a file with a long name, pressing `=` updates only the final line on screen.

For example, with the Terminal window at 80 columns and 27 rows (the default, I think), if I do:

```
less /Library/Updates/ProductMetadata.plist
```

and then press `=`, the bottom line says:

```
ss RETURN)
```

and the rest of the window doesn't change at all.  I know it knows that the other lines have different text now, though, because if I select the text with the mouse, the last two lines become:

```
/Library/Updates/ProductMetadata.plist lines 1-22/14295 byte 649/917106 0%  (pre
ss RETURN)
```

Is there any way to set up less(1) or Terminal.app so it doesn't require me to fiddle with it in order to see longer filenames?

Comment: Can't reproduce this for now, Terminal 2.5. What version of OS X/Terminal are you using?

Comment: OS X 10.9.5, Terminal 2.4.  Is it fixed in Yosemite, perhaps?

Comment: No, I can reproduce this in Terminal v2.5, OS X 10.10.2. It appears to occur if the Terminal width is <90 (which is the width of the text that appears when hitting `=`

Comment: @Scot and Ken: Which version of less are you using? I am using version 418 (which is pretty old actually).

Comment: I am also using v418 (the stock version installed on my Mac). However, I can reproduce the issue using v444 as well (on a non OS X machine).

Comment: I was using 418 (came installed with OS X 10.9), but I tried it with 458 (latest version, installed through Homebrew) just now and got exactly the same result.